# Eclipse plugins as folders rather than jars

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse tree or any eclipse based application.
I can see that inside the plugins folder.
most of plugins are in the jar format while some of them are in folders
and this folder is just the jar extract .

why someone could do this ? what is the benefit of putting a plugin as extracted jar rather than only jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to embed jars in the plugin that are used in classpath because yo can have issues with nested jars in classpath.

I think that you can also access resources differently. And it can be an easy (and dirty?)  way to allow some customizations by overriding some resources such as images.

Comment: Which details do you want?